the localhost shows - This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as fallback without any error and warning in the IDE
I'm trying to run the URL -' http://localhost:8080/products '
but browser is showing the following error :
Whitelabel Error Page


This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.


There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource products.


this is my pom.xml file :-


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.narayan</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpleWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>simpleWebApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


the response code I got is 404.
I have not defined any property in application.properties and it has worked just fine.
here is my application.properties :

spring.application.name = simpleWebApp


here is my ProductController class :



@RestController
public class ProductController {

 ProductService service;

@GetMapping("/products")
public String getProducts(){
    return service.products;
  }
}



Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Edit the question and include code fragments.

You have not defined any controller method for the default path (/). You have only defined one for /products). So you will get 404 for anything except localhost:8080/products

@JAsgarov yes for now, i just want to run localhost:8080/products successfully but I'm having trouble in that. it is showing whitelabel error even though i dont have any error or warning in the IDE.


put into question exact URL you are trying to call in your browser 2. Add the response code you get (404 or 403 or sth else) - you can see it if you open Network tab in Chrome DevTools. 3. Add error related logs 4. Add your properties so that I can see if you have defined any server.servlet.context-path or similar


@JAsgarov I did the changes you asked for. please reply. thanks.

everything seems correct and it should work. The only thing I can think of is you haven't added spring-web correctly - please show your COMPLETE pom.xml

@JAsgarov i added the complete pom.xml file. but I think I will need to make or configure changes in src/main/resources/static folder. but I can't seem to find which changes.

why don't you show your application.properties and the controller please

everything is working perfectly fine in IDE, server is also starting without any error or warning but as soon as I run the port ,it shows 404 "no static resource products". do i need to configure my "products" somewhere else too? like in diffrent folder or something?

the only thing I can think of is that you put your ProductController in some package that doesn't get scanned. Please provide the package for ProductController and also the full code of the starter class - ALSO with a package name

I created a new project which is working fine. thanks for all your help though. @JAsgarov

Is there any controller with mapping to "/products" ? If not you have to write down a controller class with a method with mapping to /products" as follows :
pakage com.demo.product;
@RestController
public class ProductController {

@GetMapping("/products")
public String getProducts(){
    return "products";
}
}

Try adding ComponentScan annotation in your spring boot application main class :
   @ComponentScan(“com.demo.product”)
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class SpringbootApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = 
            SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class, args);
    
}
}


yes, I did that too but it still won't work.

Hi,  @user26537702 you can try adding ComponentScan annotation in your spring boot application main class

I tried that too,  but it did not resolved the issue. but I created a new project which is working fine. thanks for the input though.
